# Different query parameter styles for multivalued parameters and regular ones

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a service that accepts requests with the following query parameters:

```
limit=1
param[117]=3345
```

parameters `param[117]` are `List<String>`, and parameter limit is a `string`

The service expects to receive these parameters in the following form:

`.../sevice-name?param[117][]=2233&param[117][]=3344&param[117][]=5566&limit=1`

for this I enable the setting on the client in the quarkus options

```
quarkus.rest-client."sevice-name".query-param-style=ARRAY_PAIRS
```

and get a query string like this `limit[]=1`but expected `limit=1`:

`.../sevice-name?param[117][]=2233&param[117][]=3344&param[117][]=5566&limit[]=1`

how can *quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson* be configured to get the expected behavior?

Comment: is limit parameter a collection or a single value in your method declaration?

Comment: limit parameter is a single value

Comment: based on your question I added an issue to Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24631 If you have a simple reproducer you coudl attach to the issue it would help a lot in resolving it quickly